# Handling Invalid URI passed to a WCF service

Tags: wcf, rest

I have WebGet, and WebInvoke attributes describing my contract, but what is the best method of handling invalid URI's? Right now, if a user passes an URI that does not match my current operations, they get an "Endpoint not found." message. I want to pass back a more descriptive message.

For example, my URI template looks like:

```
/Stuff/{ID}/subStuff
```

but say they type

```
/Stuff/{ID}/OtherStuff
```

There is no such thing as OtherStuff, and I do not have a template for that.

Is there a way to cover all non mapped URI's with a single contract?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I did follow the links mark provided, and they did give a hint of what I needed. The answers that were linked did not actually answer my original question.

I was able to follow the steps, and I wanted to list my steps to solve this problem on this question as well.

To create my own response to any URI that was not mapped to a method in my contract I created the following:

- A custom ServiceHostFactory
- Behavior that I mapped to my end points within the custom ServiceHostFactory
- a dispatcher that would handle all unmapped uri's that were provided to the service.

Below are the full definitions of the object's I created:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace your.namespace.here
{
    public class CustomServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            //note: these endpoints will not exist yet, if you are relying on the svc system to generate your endpoints for you
            // calling host.AddDefaultEndpoints provides you the endpoints you need to add the behavior we need.
            var endpoints = host.AddDefaultEndpoints();
            foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
            {
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WcfUnkownUriBehavior());
            }

            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above, we are adding a new behavior: WcfUnknownUriBehavior. This new custom behavior's soul duty is to replace the UnknownDispatcher. below is that implementation:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
namespace your.namespace.here
{
    public class UnknownUriDispatcher : IOperationInvoker
    {
        public object[] AllocateInputs()
        {
            //no inputs are really going to come in,
            //but we want to provide an array anyways
            return new object[1]; 
        }

        public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
        {
            var responeObject = new YourResponseObject()
            {
                Message = "Invalid Uri",
                Code = "Error",
            };
            Message result = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null, responeObject);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
            outputs = new object[1]{responeObject};
            return result;
        }

        public System.IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, System.IAsyncResult result)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsSynchronous
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have these objects specified, you can now use the new factory within your svc's "markup":

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="your.service.namespace.here" CodeBehind="myservice.svc.cs"
                Factory="your.namespace.here.CustomServiceHostFactory" %>
```

And that should be it. as long as your object "YourResponseObject" can be serialized, it's serialized representation will be sent back to the client.

Comment: where is the definition for WcfUnknownUriBehavior please?

Comment: its the custom class i wrote in the question above

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch all the unhandled requests at a global level in WCF REST then you have to create a custom `WebHttpBehavior` and custom `IOperationInvoker` as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371856/handling-404-in-wcf-rest-service).

If you want to return a custom error text with custom status code(404) you can also look into the `WebOperationContext.OutgoingResponse` property as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method).

Comment: Ok, so I have tried both techniques. both do not work, because I am relying on IIS to provide the endpoint. at the time the service is being created, the endpoint does not exist, So I can't bind a behavior.